# How to improve build time in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build

I am using VS2008.I have following script on Post-build event command line.

```
mkdir ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries

copy *.Manifest.xml ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries

copy $(TargetName).dll ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries
if exist $(TargetName).XML copy $(TargetName).XML ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries
if exist $(TargetName).pdb copy $(TargetName).pdb ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries
if exist $(TargetFileName).config copy $(TargetFileName).config ..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Modules\Libraries
```

This copies the files after each build. It is taking a long time to build because it copies all the files after each build. I just want to copy files if the file has changed after build so that it doesn't have to copy all the files and it saves build time. Is there a way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Thyake

Answer (score 0):

if you change the `copy` to `xcopy /D` it will copy only newer files.  You may need to add additional flags as well to get otherwise equivalent behavior.  Check `copy /?` and `xcopy /?` from the command line if you need more.